# Get numbers from JS code and construct an array from them

Tags: javascript, php

I have thousands of lines of code like this:

```
var coordinates = [
    new google.maps.LatLng(11.11111, 22.222222),
    new google.maps.LatLng(33.33333, 44.444444),
    new google.maps.LatLng(55.55555, 66.666666),

    //Thousands of lines
];
```

I need to format code above to array of LatLng arrays containing Lat and Lng separately:

---

```
[0] => [lat] => [11.11111], [lng] => [22.22222]
[1] => [lat] => [33.33333], [lng] => [44.44444]
[2] => [lat] => [55.55555], [lng] => [66.66666]

//etc
```

Doing it one by one on my own would take forever. I need to hardcode the outcome to my code which means it would be best if I could build a frontend *converter* with (2) textarea(s) where I could copy my 1st code, press button and get the results which I could copy-paste to my own code.

`PHP` and `JS` both works for me, choose the language you like.

**How to get numbers from my 1st block of code and build the structure in my second code?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Array.prototype.map() to transform your array:

```
var result = coordinates.map(function(point) {
    return {
        lat: point.lat(),
        lng: point.lng()
    };
});

// access it
console.log(result[0].lat);
// or
console.log(result[0]['lat'];
```

Comment: This works perfectly. However, is there a way to name arrays? I currently get _Object-s_ that contain `lat` and `lng`, I would love to rename it.

Comment: @Solo what do you mean - rename object?